# What is the default file system for ClamAV scans?

Tags: linux, clamav, debian-buster

I have just installed ClamAV on a Pi4 running Buster.  I have looked at the configuration file and don't see where it specifies which file system it will scan automatically.  I know if I use this `sudo clamscan  /home` or `sudo clamscan  /` it will scan the "home" directory or "whole file system", respectively.  But what is the default for the regular, automatic scans?

Thanks...RDK

Answer (score 2):

`clamscan` scans *nothing* by default. You need to pass/configure a specific path to scan it. After finished, it exits immediately.

`clamd` is its service counterpart: when running, it listen on a socket for incoming data to scan. Such data must be feed by an external program as a mailserver or an anti-spam service. Again, it scan *nothing* by default.

Comment: OK, do I have to define the socket/"feeder" program?  How and where?  It is going to be on an e-mail server which also has a resident webserver